# File naming convention for JSP

Tags: jsp, naming-conventions, filenames

Is there an industry-standard naming convention for JSP files?

I have come across three conventions from different sources:

1. All lowercase  (**thisismyfile.jsp**)
2. Camel case with the first letter lowercase (**thisIsMyFile.jsp**)
3. Camel case with the first letter uppercase (**ThisIsMyFile.jsp**)

Comment: As long as the chosen convention is used in the whole project, it's a good convention. Public URLs are likely to be rewritten in the end, so it's only an internal matter.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Updated Answer - 2019**

Since this question was first answered, it looks like Oracle has added a naming convention section to their document: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/code-convention-138726.html

> **JSP Names**
>
> A JSP (file) name should always begin with a lower-case
>   letter. The name may consist of multiple words, in which case the
>   words are placed immediately adjacent and each word commences with an
>   upper-case letter.

So `thisIsMyFile.jsp` (above) is the choice that best matches the convention.

---

**Original Answer from 2013**

Here's the closest thing I could find to an official naming convention: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/code-convention-138726.html.

It appears that Sun/Oracle has no opinion on the filenames.

My 2 cents:  I prefer to go all lower case.  It minimizes the likelyhood of porting problems.  For example porting from Windows to Unix (a case-sensitive operating system) could result in case issues.

Comment: Answer by Kamiel Ahmadpour here refers to an actual Oracle opinion (camelCase option 2. in the question).
Although maybe it's not really a good convention in the first place, for reasons like EJK's here of OS differences, as well as web server differences.

Answer (score 15):

> JSP (file) name should always begin with a lower-case letter. The name may consists of multiple words, in which case the words are placed immediately adjacent and each word commences with an upper-case letter. A JSP name can be just a simple noun or a short sentence. A verb-only JSP name should be avoided, as it does not convey sufficient information to developers.

Example: performLogin.jsp

Here is complete reference:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/namingconventions-139351.html

Answer (score 2):

On the flip side, jsp is still a Java file in the end and should be named accordingly.

```
performLogin.jsp -> PerformLogin.jsp
```

It also helps in cases where you need to resolve interface or class names by JSP name.

Answer (score 1):

According to [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6PEW_9.4.0/com.ibm.help.custom.consolejsp.doc/JSP_Conventions_JSP_FileDir.html), jsp file should be named all lowercase and separate by underscore ("_") characters.

Eg: `orderline_search_bydate.jsp`